# How to change the clickable area of a SpriteKit Sprite Node from rectangle to circle?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, geometry, skspritenode

I have a play button on my menu screen but it detects touches in the area of the entire rectangle instead of just the circle.  Is there any way to change the clickable bounds to a circle either within xcode?

Or will i have to programmatically do it within initialization or a function:

```
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {}
```

[image: PlayButton]

Comment: Post the original button image. Are you sure the image is transparent?

Comment: this is the button image, and you can see its transparent, it is just selected on xcode to show the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it programmatically to the GameScene.

```
   var playButton: SKSpriteNode!



   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
         playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButton")
         playButton.name = "playButton"
         playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY)
         playButton.zPosition = 0
         playButton.alpha = 1

         addChild(playButton)
   }



  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }
    
    let pos = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = self.atPoint(pos)

    if node.name == "playButton"{

       //Do Something
    }
     

  }
```

Comment: did that, but the bounds are still the same on the image so if i select the blue area in that image around the corner and im not touching the circle, but it still registers as if it was clicked.  What i need is for those bounds to be in a circle instead of a rect. then it would work.